# Is it possible to an user login more than once to a Windows Server with Remote Desktop/Terminal Services?

Tags: remote-desktop-services

I've tried this, and it was not possible.
But maybe there's a config that allows this. idk.

Is it possible?

I'm getting the user SessionID based on the explorer.exe process that belongs to them. But, if users can log more than once, they will have many explorer.exe and also many SessionIDs. So there would be a flaw in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Policy

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Connections\Restrict
>   Terminal Services users to a single remote session

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731606(WS.10).aspx

> If you enable this policy setting, users who log on remotely by using
>   Terminal Services will be restricted to a single session (either
>   active or disconnected) on that server. If the user leaves the session
>   in a disconnected state, the user automatically reconnects to that
>   session at next logon.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, users are allowed to make
>   unlimited simultaneous remote connections by using Terminal Services.

For Windows 2008R2 the path is... 
     \Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections

Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session = Disabled